# Optimisation of jQuery file checking

Tags: jquery, optimization

**Background**

We are creating an information management system for a bunch of clinics in South Africa. A part of this system is a photo gallery for each clinic. The number of photos per clinic aren't limited.

**Problem**

Since we will need to upload around 400 clinics' data, we needed an easy system that allows for a 'one go' upload. I wrote a jQuery function that - when the upload input is changed - basically checks the name of the file, and according to that name, divides it into sections (according to the clinic names)

The issues is, when I add a lot of files, the time it takes to process is forever. It takes around 5 minutes to process 600 files. And that's just to divide them into the sections.

**The Code**

```
$("#UploadFiles").on('change',function() {
    $("#UploadAddForm").fadeOut(200,function() {
        $(".info").fadeIn(200);
    });
    for (var i=0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        var file = this.files[i];
        file.ext = file.name.substr(file.name.lastIndexOf('.')+1).toLowerCase();
        file.icon = '../img/icon/file_extension_' + file.ext + '.png';
        file.category = fileObject[file.ext] ? fileObject[file.ext] : 'Unknown';
        file.owner = file.name.substr(0,file.name.indexOf('_'));
        $.ajax({
            url: 'checkClinic/'+file.owner,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if(!data) {
                    file.owner = 'Unknown';
                }
            }
        });
        file.div = file.owner.replace(/ /g,"_");
        $("#UploadAddForm").append(
            $('<input type="hidden">').attr({
                'name' : 'data[FileData][' + i + '][name]',
                'id' : 'FileData'+i+'Name',
                'value' : file.name
            })
        ).append(
            $('<input type="hidden">').attr({
                'name' : 'data[FileData][' + i + '][owner]',
                'id' : 'FileData'+i+'Owner',
                'class' : 'file_owner',
                'value' : file.owner
            })
        );
        if($('#' + file.div).length > 0 || file.owner == 'Unknown') {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            $('.info').append(
                $('<div>').attr({
                    'id' : file.div,
                    'class' : 'file_holder'
                }).html('<h3>' + file.owner + '</h3>')
            );
        }
        if(file.category != 'Unknown' && file.owner != 'Unknown') {
            $holder = $('#' + file.div);
        } else {
            $holder = $('.unknown-files');
            $('#FileData'+i+'Owner').val('unknown');
        }
        $($holder).append(
            $('<div>').attr({
                class: 'fake_file',
                'input': '#FileData'+i+'Owner',
                id: 'File'+i+'Selector'
            }).html('<img src="' + file.icon + '">&nbsp;' + file.name).draggable({
                opacity: 0.7,
                revert: "invalid",
                stack: '.file_holder'
            })
        ).droppable({
            accept: ".fake_file",
            drop: function(event,ui) {
                $(this).append(ui.draggable);
                $(ui.draggable).animate({
                    left: 0,
                    top: 0
                });
                $(ui.draggable.attr('input')).val($(this).attr('id').replace(/_/g," "));
            }
        });

        if(file.category == 'image') {
            $("#UploadAddForm").append(
                $('<input type="hidden">').attr({
                    'name' : 'data[FileData][' + i + '][cover]',
                    'id' : 'FileData'+i+'Cover',
                    'value' : 'No'
                })
            );
            $('#File'+i+'Selector').append(
                $('<input>').attr({
                    type: 'radio',
                    name: file.div,
                    id: 'File'+i,
                    'cover': '#FileData'+i+'Cover',
                    class: 'cover-selector',
                }).on(
                'click',function(e) {
                    $name = $(this).attr('name');
                    $.each($('input[name="' + $name + '"]'),function(i,v) {
                        $($(this).attr('cover')).val('No');
                    });
                    $($(this).attr('cover')).val('Yes');
                })
            ).append(
                $('<label>').attr({
                    'for': 'File'+i
                }).html('Cover')
            );
        }
    }
    $('.info').append(
        $('<div>').attr({
            'class' : 'submit'
        }).append(
            $('<input>').attr({
                'type' : 'submit',
                'value' : 'Upload',
                'class' : 'submit-upload'
            })
        )
    );
    $('.submit-upload').on('click',function() {
        $('#UploadAddForm').submit();
    });
});
```

**Question**

Is there any way that I can optimise this code? It works and does exactly what it needs to do, but it just takes too long to do it.

**Additional Info**

I realise that I might not be 100% clear. So I'm adding a few pictures.

This is what the page looks like when I first load it:

[image]

Then, I select files:

[image]

If I select a lot of files in the step above, it takes forever to process, before it shows this page:

[image]

As stated, it works fine, it just takes forever to run, so I want to know if there is any way I can optimise it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the bottleneck is the upload. How much bandwidth do you have and how large are the files?

You should try exactly the same code with tiny (~1KB) but numerous (hundreds) of files.
If that is quick then the problem is just the file size and bandwidth you have.

The second thing that comes to my mind is this. At the beginning of your code you have:

```
$("#UploadAddForm").fadeOut(200,function() {
    $(".info").fadeIn(200);
});
```

Now, is this executed for each file? If so, it might be that the queue of changes fires this piece for each file. You say 5 minutes for 600 files, that's 500 ms per file. The fade in/out would take 200+200=400 ms per file. Approximately we are there.

As a test, I'd lower that fade in/out down to 1 ms (next to instant) and test if this is the problem.

Comment: That's the thing. At this point it's not yet uploading. If you look at the code, it's all jQuery running on the local machine. It's basically just running through all the files selected in the upload field. It's not uploading anything yet. EDIT: Saw your edit - Can't be, because that is only run once. `$('#UploadFiles') == <input type="file" name="data[Upload][files][]" multiple="multiple" id="UploadFiles" required="required">` thus it runs when the input is changed. And only once.